# Assigning a Variable in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, variable-assignment

I am a newbie in Android. Can you teach me on how to assign a variable in editText? See code the example below.

```
EditText assignVariable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.variable);

if(assignVariable == 12 ) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Assign Varialbe Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Successfully Assign!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please Explain bit more. assign a variable in EditText what do you mean by this.? what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Try this : if(Integer.parseInt(assignVariable.getText().toString()) == 12 )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set text in edittext, then you can use:

```
assignVariable.setText("your text goes here");
```

If you need to retrieve text from edittext, you would need to put this code on button click. (not just after initialization of EditText.)

```
String assignedText = assignVariable.getText().toString();
```

And you can't compare String with `==` operator. You should use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

```
if (assignedText.equals("12")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Assign Varialbe Successfull",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Successfully Assign!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I mean is this. I want to assign a integer value in editText like for example number 12. if the editText number is equal to 12 success if not not success

Comment: Assign variable means tag? If so, use ngesh's answer. I think that's good. Because, your question was not so clear. @user3912595

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText assignVariable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.variable);

if(assignVariable.getText().toString().equals("12") ) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Assign Varialbe Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Successfully Assign!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return true;
}
```